# error: redefinition of 'var' with a different type: 'char' vs 'string' (aka 'basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >')

Tags: c++, string, initialization

```
void allocateChar(string type, string var, int length, char initToChar){
    char *Thingy = (char*)myMalloc(length);
    char var = initToChar;
    my_free(Thingy);

}
```

I'm getting the error on char var = initToChar and i'm not sure why i'm getting it because based off what i've seen on Google, this error occurs for naming 2 different things the same thing. However, I don't believe i'm doing that because i'm taking whatever the user inputs for the name as a string and then setting it as the char's name.

Comment: You used the name `var` in the argument, and used the name `var` again in the declaration of a local variable, so that is causing the error. What do you want to do?

Comment: Unless proved wrong, I'd bet on the compiler being correct.

Comment: " I don't believe i'm doing that" DO NOT believe what is wrong in debugging.

Comment: also you never used `Thingy`

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> ... However, I don't believe i'm doing that ...

That's not true, you are. You are creating two distinct variables with the same name in the same scope. Which isn't allowed.